# How do I fix: GET http://... 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have made a JS game. However, nothing shows up on the screen on localhost. When I check the console, I get the following error:

GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NMFSX-v 404 (Not Found)

What does this error mean? How do I fix it?

code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/game.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").
        getContext("2d");
        ctx.fint = '30px Arial'

        var socket = io();

        socket.on('newPosition', function(data) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            ctx.fillText('P', data.x, data.y);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <div class="circle"></div> -->
    <script src="../js/game.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(_req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '../clients/index.html');
});
app.use('../clients', express.static(__dirname + '../clients'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started.");

var SOCKET_LIST = {};

var io = require('socket.io') (serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.id = Math.random()
    socket.x = 0;
    socket.y = 0;
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
});

setInterval(function(){
    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        socket.x++
        socket.y++
        socket.emit('newPosition', {
            x:socket.x,
            y:socket.y
        })
    };

},1000/25);
```

Please can you make sure to post potential solutions in the Answers section?

Thank you SO much for your help!!!

**Edit: Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: err... is the code at the bottom, server.js? because, that... isn't quite right.

Comment: Doing a search on "http error 404" brought back "About 202,000,000 results" when searching a popular search engine...

Comment: @TheBombSquad if you can't find a duplicate, go ahead and answer. cmon, that's how this site works :P

Comment: `..js/server.js` implies that you have a directory called `..js`. `../js` would be a directory called `js` within the parent directory. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: from the looks of it there r 2 places at least(also most likely spots) where the server isn't serving.. `res.sendFile`, `theActualPlaceYouTryToGetThis`

Comment: user said the 3rd one

Comment: run ur thing again and load from browser `localhost:2000`

Comment: @user4642212 ah yes, you are right. i noticed this in my code and fixed it minutes before reading your comment. nevertheless, it still does not work

Comment: i assume that error is happening on the browser right... and socketio.js tries to fetch this weird link

Comment: i saw something in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510159/socket-io-err-name-not-resolved ... try replacing `var socket = io()` to `var socket=io.connect(aURL)`

Comment: @SiannaZewdie i found out how some strange url tries to be fetched... the `io()` with no options does that(ik this cuz i copied the code from https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js) and tried to socket the same way you did

Comment: idk how the script from that site works but it seems that `io.connect("localhost:2000")` should work because your server side socket listens to port `2000`

Comment: @TheBombSquad ok! so, should i put this where it says `var socket = io() ?`

Comment: look, the reason why the error is happening(not that i know 100% fix for it) is that in ur html tab, u load from that page i mentioned earlier.. just running the function `io` without params IS the reason why it tries fetching some weird url

Comment: no...sorry! it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error starts under the line

```
var io = require('socket.io') (serv,{});
```

try this block for the lines under instead

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var socketID=Math.floor(Math.random())*80
    while(SOCKET_LIST[socketID]!=undefined){
      socketID=Math.floor(Math.random())*80
    }
    //all that drama above is to(at least meant to) prevent socket overlap(just in case that solves a problem)
    socket.id = socketID
    socket.x = 0;
    socket.y = 0;
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
});

setInterval(function(){
    Object.keys(SOCKET_LIST).forEach((a,i)=>{
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        socket.x++
        socket.y++
        socket.emit('newPosition', {
            x:socket.x,
            y:socket.y
        })
    })

},1000/25);
```

if this doesn't work then the problem is what the frontend tries to access(reason for that 100% strange link it tried to access)

Comment: did it give the exact same error(sry my school is now over)

Comment: @SiannaZewdie was it the same error or some new error? also add to the question a screenshot of the error pls

Comment: ive added a screenshot

Answer (score -2):

> 404 (Not Found)

It is the http-error-code for not finding an url.

**Edit:**
In your given script you call the js-file from the Content Delivery Network of socket.io: "https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js".

Check your local script if you mayby made a mistake with transforming it to  "http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NMFSX-v"

Comment: i think he would know that

Comment: He just asked it.

Comment: @selcox How is the definition of `404`, which is already mentioned in the title of the question, a helpful answer? How is _“How to fix 404 (Not Found)?” — “404 means not found”_ helpful?

Comment: @user4642212 After all I can't find the link "http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NMFSX-v " in the given source code. The error-code belongs to the url that stand in front of 404.

Comment: @selcox what kind of mistake should i check for in my local script?

Comment: by the way, i'm a she

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault. I didn't pay that much attention to the name. Es tut mir leid. :-)